# D3 update tick values without updating the domain

Tags: d3.js

I have an x-axis with long tick names, and I want to provide their abbreviations as tick values. Long tick names are used to set the domain.

```
        axisElement = d3.axisBottom(scale)
            .tickValues(tickValues); // these are long names when axis is first drawn
        chart.append("g")
            .attr("class", "bottomAxis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height + ")")
            .call(axisElement);
```

I first draw the axis with proper long names which looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/81V9A), and then try to update the ticks using `axis.tickValues()` function in D3.

```
updateTicks(tickValues) {
        chart.select(".bottomAxis").call(this.axisElement.tickValues(tickValues));
    }
```

But when D3 draws the ticks, it uses the old domain values in scale (which are the long names) and messes up the positioning of abbreviated names. It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGkw1.jpg). I also get the following error:

```
Error: <g> attribute transform: Expected number, "translate(NaN,0)".
```

Which, I believe, is saying that it tried to translate the tick according to old domain values, but found abbreviated value so it can't translate.

I tried changing the scale's domain to abbreviated names, and then D3 positions them appropriately.

My question is, is it possible to change tickValues without changing the domain values?

Comment: Why don't you start with the abbreviations to begin with? Why set the long names first and then update?

Comment: I need the domain scale with long names for other charts in the same graphic. It's part of charting library I am building and the long names are necessary for other components. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like the following. You need to call `axisBottom` on your `svg` element and then use `tickFormat` to set the abbreviated text values. I have included a small example in the fiddle to show you. In the example, I am initially setting the long tick values first by default and then changing it to the abbreviated ones like you want to do.

```
var abbr = ["ll1", "ll2", "ll3", "ll4"];

svg
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(function(d, i) {
    return abbr[i];
  }));
```

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/tkw07c96/

Comment: Thanks for the working example. I ended up wrapping up the long names using Mike's example here: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321